# Assigning a value to a object's property/variable in a callback

Tags: javascript

```
var obj1={
    var1:"val1",
    init:function(){
        this.var1="val2";
        var self=this;
        setTimeout(function(){self.var1="val3"},1);
        setTimeout(function(){obj1.var1="val3"},1);
    }
}

obj1.init();
console.log(obj1.var1);
console.log(obj1);
```

How to set/assign a value to var1 in the setTimeout callback. Assigning val3 does not have an effect and as seen in the screenshot we have two properties mentioned as var1 now. 1 is var1=val2 and other is var1=val3 , but this.var1 always returns val2 not val3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the value is set to "var3" in your code. But in your demo, the console prints "var2" is because that `console.log()` fire earlier then that setTimeout(). The variable changes after it print out.

check [this jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6HZE/1/) for correct result.